# JSON response to HTML ouput

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have this sql data, whish I used ajax and I already got the response. My problem is the response that I got need to be viewed on html, Help..

this is my script and HTML code, Kindly check this for me, Thanks

```js
 function view_info(information) {

  // jConfirm( "<b> Do you want to view the information of this applicant?</b>" + "<br><br>", "Confirm", function(r){
  //     if (r){
  //         newwindow=window.open("<?php echo base_url()?>fg_summary/get_info/" + information,"name","scrollbars=1,height=768,width=950");
  //         if (window.focus) newwindow.focus();
  //     }
  // });
  // alert('test');

  $('#myModal').trigger('click');

 }


  $("#myModal").click(function(){


  // var _COC_NO     = $("#btn_info").parent().parent().find("td").eq(2).html();

  var _COC_NO = document.getElementById("coc").innerHTML;
  var _DEP_COC_NO   = document.getElementById("depcoc").innerHTML;

   $.ajax({
    type :"POST",
    url  :'<?php echo base_url("fg_summary/get_view"); ?>',
    timeout:    10000, 
    data : {
     COC_NO          : _COC_NO,
     DEP_COC_NO        : _DEP_COC_NO,
    },
    success: function(result){
     var _result = $.parseJSON(result);
     alert(_result);

       $.each(_result['MSG'], function() {
                table += '<tr><td>' + this['firstName'] + '</td><td>' + this['lastName'] + '</td></tr>';
            });


        var table = '<table><thead><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></thead><tbody>';
            table += '</tbody></table>';
            document.getElementById("myModal").innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Read and Parse JSON String in jQuery | Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        border: 1px solid #777;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    } 

    table tr th,
    table tr td {
        border: 1px solid #777;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="width:1000px">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Information</h4>
        </div>
          <div class="modal-body">


        <div id="datalist">
        </div>

        </div>    
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var jsonobj = eval("(" + result + ")");
  $.each(jsonobj, function(i,val) {
                            table += '<tr><td>' + jsonobj['firstName'] + '</td><td>' + jsonobj['lastName'] + '</td></tr>';
                        });


                        var table = '<table><thead><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></thead><tbody>';
                        table += '</tbody></table>';
                            document.getElementById("myModal").innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: hi, this code doesnt work, I already get the value of response thru this code //alert(_result.SEARCH_CODE);
// alert(_result.MSG[0].COC_NO); and the problem now was I need the value of response that I got to be displayed on my html.. Many Thanks